# Fog-Google, Unable to Push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i am trying to set up uploading of files in my production environment. I am currently using CarrierWave along with Fog-Google. I have no issues storing files locally as i do not use Fog for development. However i am currently trying to test out the file uploading functionality in production, but i cannot even push my app up to Heroku.

Here's a snippet of the error i'm receiving when attempting to push to Heroku.

```
[fog][WARNING] Unrecognized arguments: google_storage_secret_access_key_id, google_storage_secret_access_key
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: Invalid keyfile or passphrase
```

Now i am relatively new to setting up ENV secret ids and all of that. So instead i'll just say what i know and what i have done just to be sure that i did everything correctly.

So as i am currently using Cloud9 IDE, in my `.bashrc` file i have

```
export GOOGLE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXX
export GOOGLE_STORAGE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=XXXXX
export GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME=XXXXX
```

In my `/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb`

```
require 'carrierwave'

CarrierWave.configure do |config|
  config.fog_provider = 'fog/google'                        # required
  config.fog_credentials = {
    provider:                         'Google',
    google_storage_access_key_id:     ENV['GOOGLE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
    google_storage_secret_access_key: ENV['GOOGLE_STORAGE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
  }
  config.fog_directory = ENV['GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME']
end
```

and in my `/config/initializers/fog.rb`

```
GoogleStorage = Fog::Storage.new(
  provider: 'Google',
  google_project: 'XXXX',
  google_client_email: 'XXXXXX',
  google_key_location: Rails.root.join('private','google-cloud-service-key.p12'),
  google_storage_secret_access_key_id: ENV["GOOGLE_STORAGE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID"],
  google_storage_secret_access_key: ENV["GOOGLE_STORAGE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"]
)
```

Like mentioned i am actually quite new to all of these so i've tried my best in following the documentation on both Fog and CarrierWave's github page.

As far as i know i should use `.bashrc` to store my secret keys etc and then call on them using `ENV['SECRET_KEY_NAME']` method. I've set up both the CarrierWave.rb and Fog.rb files in the initializer folder so i'm not quite sure what i'm missing as well.

Additionally i have also tried doing `heroku config:set GOOGLE_STORAGE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID=XXXXXX` but that didn't seem to work as well.

I'm not quite sure what to do now and what may be causing the error when attempting to push to Heroku, much less whether any of this is even working in production.

EDIT:

I think the error is largely from the `fog.rb` file. So i amended it to the following:

```
GoogleStorage = Fog::Storage::Google.new(
  google_project: 'XXX',
  google_client_email: 'XXX',
  google_json_key_location: '~/.fog/XXXX.json'
)
```

And now when i try pushing to Heroku the error i get instead is

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /app/.fog/XXX.json
```

Just to share, i created a `.fog` folder under the `~` directory. Inside the `.fog` folder i added in the Private JSON key.

All help and advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: have you pushed after `heroku config:set`?

Comment: @Aleksey yes i have tried after `heroku config:set` and i'm still receiving the same errors.

Comment: maybe you can try `Fog::Storage::Google` instead of just  `Fog::Storage`

Comment: @Aleksey doesn't seem to be working although now i think the problem is indeed with the Fog.rb file. After amending it to `Fog::Storage::Google` the error message when trying to push to Heroku included `Unrecognized Arguments: Provider`

Comment: I was going to write it in the previous comment: try to delete `provider` key since I already use `Fog::Storage::Google` class

Comment: @Aleksey after some fiddling around i am currently getting a different error. Not sure where i should be storing my Private Key JSON file and also how to link to it correctly.

Comment: `/app/.fog` on Heroku means `.fog` within your app directory. So it shouldn't be under `~`, it should be under your `Rails.root`. Try to change `google_json_key_location` to `Rails.root.join('.fog/XXXX.json')`

Comment: @Aleksey hey thank you so much for your help with this! i managed to push the code to Heroku! I'm not sure if Fog-Google is functioning properly and sync-ed with my Google Cloud Platform or not but that's a nice start. I'll be testing it out anyways. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

So i've solved the problem and managed to successfully push my code to Heroku.

[Kindly note that this does not mean it functions perfectly in production, it just means i am now able to push to Heroku without any errors]

So there were 2 main errors.

1) Not including my Private Key JSON file in my app.

2) Error in the `config/initializers/fog.rb` file

To solve the first issue, i created a `.fog` folder in my App and added in my Private Key JSON file which was from Google's Cloud Platform.

Next i amended the code in `config/initializers/fog.rb` to:

```
GoogleStorage = Fog::Storage::Google.new(
  :google_project => 'XXXX',
  :google_client_email => 'XXXXX',
  :google_json_key_location => Rails.root.join('.fog/XXXX'),
  :google_storage_access_key_id => ENV['GOOGLE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :google_storage_secret_access_key => ENV['GOOGLE_STORAGE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)
```

I was then able to successfully push my code to Heroku.